# Changing arrowhead style

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-arrows, tikz-styles

I would like to change the style of my arrowheads. I looked up and found a solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30822634/how-to-change-arrow-tip-in-tikz). However, it doesn't work in my case, and I'm wondering what went wrong. Here is my MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\usetikzlibrary{arrows,decorations.markings}
\tikzset{myptr/.style={decoration={markings,mark=at position 1 with %
{\arrow[scale=3,>=stealth]{>}}},postaction={decorate}}}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw [myptr] (3,0) -- (5,0);
\draw [->, in=180, out=0, looseness=1] (0, -3) to (2, 3);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Here is the output:

[image]

Clearly, the arrowhead on the curved line is not the one shown horizontally. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Do not use `arrow` - it is deprecated. -use `arrow.meta` with capitalised arrow tip names such as `Stealth`, `Latex`, ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=1cm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\tikzset{
myptr/.style={-{Stealth[scale=3]}},
}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[myptr] (3,0) -- (5,0);
\coordinate (A) at (0,-3);
\coordinate (B) at (2,3);
\draw[-{Stealth[scale=3]}] (A) to[out=0, in=180, looseness=1] (B);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: A curved and a straight arrow]

**Edit:** Maybe you are trying to change the default arrow tip like this:

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=1cm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[>={Stealth[scale=3]}]
\draw[->] (3,0) -- (5,0);
\coordinate (A) at (0,-3);
\coordinate (B) at (2,3);
\draw[->] (A) to[out=0, in=180, looseness=1] (B);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

-or use `\tikzset{>={Stealth[scale=3]}}` to have the change in the whole document.

Comment: Thanks! So in line -3 of the code, I see that replacing "-{Stealth[scale=3]}" by "myptr" works as well. So, in all, I needed to use "arrows.meta" instead of "arrows"?

Comment: `myptr` is a style defined by you to be `-{Stealth[scale=3]}`. Styles are a good idea, if you want to have more lines(arrows) of this type.