Draw several cars with TikZ and and special style arrows
I need help to get the updated result below


I have drawn several cars with this code:

\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\tikzset{
    pics/my car/.style={
        code={
            \tikzset{my car/.cd, #1}
            \shade[my car/car color, shading angle={135},
                draw=black, rounded corners=1.2ex, very thick] 
                (1.5,.5) -- ++(0,1) -- ++(1,0.3) --  ++(3,0) -- ++(1,0) 
                    -- ++(0,-1.3) -- (1.5,.5) -- cycle;
            \draw[very thick, rounded corners=0.5ex, fill=black!20!blue!20!white, thick]
                (2.5,1.8) -- ++(1,0.7) -- ++(1.6,0) -- ++(0.6,-0.7) -- (2.5,1.8);
            \draw[thick] (4.2,1.8) -- (4.2,2.5);
            \draw[fill=gray!50, thick] 
                (2.75,.5) circle[radius=.5cm]
                (5.5,.5) circle[radius=.5cm];
            \draw[fill=gray!80, semithick] 
                (2.75,.5) circle[radius=.4cm]
                (5.5,.5) circle[radius=.4cm];
            \coordinate (-front) at (1.5,1);
            \coordinate (-back) at (6.5,1);
            \coordinate (-top) at (4.25,2.5);
            \coordinate (-bottom) at (4.25,0);
        }
    },
    my car/car color/.style={
        top color=red, bottom color=white
    }
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\pic (car 1) at (0,0) {my car};    

\pic (car 2) at (10,0) {my car={car color/.append style={top color=blue}}};  

\pic (car 3) at (20,0) {my car={car color/.append style={top color=green}}};  

\pic (car 4) at (30,0) {my car={car color/.append style={top color=black}}};  

%\draw[<-, shorten <=5pt, shorten >=5pt, ultra thick] 
  %  (car 1-back) -- (car 2-front);

\draw[line width=5pt][<-, shorten <=5pt, shorten >=5pt] 
    (car 1-top) to[out=90, in=90] (car 2-top);
  \draw[line width=5pt][<-, shorten <=5pt, shorten >=5pt] 
  (car 2-top) to[out=90, in=90] (car 3-top);
   \draw[line width=5pt][<-, shorten <=5pt, shorten >=5pt] 
  (car 3-top) to[out=90, in=90] (car 4-top);

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}


Where exactly is the point you got stuck at? Your code is compileable and for me it seems like you'd already figured out 90% of the work.

@DraUX I want the output of my code to be exactly like the form I sent. But I don't know if, for example, my arrows will be exactly like the shape or the shape of the cars

If you want it to be exactly like the picture I would use the picture itself. It is quite difficult to draw something with that amount of detail. If you just want to add the missing arrows and change their style you can probably check some other questions, since this should be answered sufficiently on this site. Maybe start here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/672383/changing-arrowhead-style

I believe I have seen arrows like those between the cars somewhere on this site, but was unable to find it,  One can use calc notation locate points between node anchors (north weat, etc.)

You can find code for cars, trams and buses at https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/235535/.

Update 2
I'm sorry the code is a bit obscure here, but detailed results require that, in the new thing there is modifying the text size in the nodes using font=, and then controlling the spacing of the node box using inner xsep and inner ysep, also of the line widths, then in repetitive things where it is somewhat difficult to understand that for each iteration something will be drawn based on the conditions, for example for iteration 2 do nothing if iterates up to 5, then other conditions if it iterates up to 4.
Note that now the vehicle is obtained from a capture using the image clipping tool obtained in Windows in Spanish, which is saved by default with the name captura.jpg and saved in the same directory where the tex file is.
U2 Result:

U2 MWE:
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{mathptmx}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,arrows.meta,backgrounds,decorations.markings}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[%Here you can define some tikz picture enviroment options
        font=\normalsize,%set al fonts of this environment \sf=serif family, and size of text
        Arrow/.style 2 args= {%Custom style arrow named Arrow, that has 2 arguments
            draw=#1,%Option draw=color, #1 is the first argument
            >={Triangle[angle=120:.5cm 0.3,scale length=0.5*#2,scale width=0.3*#2]},%It uses arrows meta arrow personalization, check visual tikz normal definition is ->
            line width=#2*1.2mm
        },
        ArrowColor/.store in=\ArrowColor,ArrowColor=black,%Some variable to use in other styles below
        ArCorr/.store in=\ArCorr,ArCorr=1.5, %Some variable to use in other styles below
        Thickness/.store in=\Thickness,Thickness=4pt,%Some variable to use in other styles below
        W/.store in=\W,W=5mm,%Some variable to use in other styles below
        Arrow2/.style={%custom style arrow using decoratins markings.
            draw=none,
            postaction={
                decorate,
                decoration={
                    markings,
                    mark= at position 0 %this draw will be the first mark at the start of the path
                    with {%Mark drawing definition
                        \begin{scope}[yscale=#1]%All is in scope to mirror it using the default argument #1, using as Arrow2=-1 or 1
                            \pgfmathparse{int(\pgfdecoratedpathlength/4)}%Obtain the leght of the path
                            \edef\H{\pgfmathresult/15}%Then adjuts to mach the size of coordinates to the lenght of the path.
                            \fill[fill=\ArrowColor]
                            (0,0)
                            to [out=90-15, in=180] (\H,\W/1.5) coordinate (b)
                            -- ++(\Thickness,0) -- ++(0,-1pt) 
                            to [out=180, in=90-15] (\Thickness,0)
                            -- (0,0);
                        \end{scope}
                    }
                }
            },
            postaction={
                decorate,
                decoration={
                    markings,
                    mark=at position 1 %this draw will be the last mark at the end of the path
                    with {
                        \begin{scope}[yscale=#1]%idem
                            \pgfmathparse{int(\pgfdecoratedpathlength/4)}%idem
                            \edef\H{\pgfmathresult/15}%idem
                            \fill[fill=\ArrowColor]
                            (b) %uses previos coodinate to draw in the marck
                            to [out=0, in=90+20] (\Thickness/2,\Thickness*\ArCorr/1.5)
                            -- (\Thickness*\ArCorr,\Thickness*\ArCorr/1.5)
                            -- (0,0)
                            -- (-\Thickness*\ArCorr,\Thickness*\ArCorr/1.5)
                            -- (-\Thickness/2,\Thickness*\ArCorr/1.5)
                            to [out=90+20, in=0] ($(b)+(0,-1pt)$)
                            -- (b);
                        \end{scope}
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        ]
        
        %Creating a weel for all cars
        \def\Weel#1{%\Weel{position}
            \draw[fill=white,shift={(#1)}](0,0)circle (0.3);
            \draw[fill=black!80, even odd rule,shift={(#1)}](0,0) circle (.3) circle (0.2);
            \draw[fill,shift={(#1)}](0,0) circle (0.08);
            \foreach \i in {1,...,12}{\draw[fill,shift={(#1)}](30*\i:0.1)--(30*\i:0.2)--+(90+30*\i:0.02);}        
        }
        
        % drawing the Cars from external archives, you may include vectors (svg for example) if you convert them to pdf format.
        \draw(0,0) node[anchor=-90](CAR-1){\includegraphics[width=3cm]{captura.jpg}}; %\draw(position) node [node options](node_name){\includegraphics[graphic options]{imagefile}}
        \draw($(CAR-1.-90)+(4.5,0)$) node[anchor=-90](CAR-2){\includegraphics[width=3cm]{captura.jpg}};
        \draw($(CAR-2.-90)+(4.5,0)$) node[anchor=-90](CAR-3){\includegraphics[width=3cm]{captura.jpg}};
        \draw($(CAR-3.-90)+(4.5,0)$) node[anchor=-90](CAR-4){\includegraphics[width=3cm]{captura.jpg}};
        \draw($(CAR-4.-90)+(3,0)$) node[scale=3]{$\dots$};
        \draw($(CAR-4.-90)+(6,1)$) node[draw, line width=3pt,font={\large},inner xsep=20pt,inner ysep=10pt](L){Leader};%modified
        \Weel{$(L)+(-0.8,-0.7)$}
        \Weel{$(L)+(0.8,-0.7)$} 
        \draw($(CAR-2)+(0,4)$) node[draw, line width=2pt,font={\large},inner xsep=20pt,inner ysep=10pt](C){Controller $C_i$};%modified
        
        %Drawing some Arrows
        \draw[Arrow={cyan!40!blue}{1.2},->](CAR-1.120) |- ($(C)+(-1,2)$) -| (C.150);% |:vertical -:horizontal
        \draw[Arrow={cyan!40!blue}{1.2},->](CAR-2.120) coordinate (temp) -- (C.-90-|temp);% node_coord intersectión perpendicular tipe (-| or |-)
        \draw[Arrow={cyan!40!blue}{1.2},->]($(L.90)+(0,0.5em)$) |- ($(C)+(1,2)$) -| (C.120);
        \draw[Arrow={cyan!40!blue}{1.2},->](CAR-4.120) |- ($(C)+(1,1.5)$) -| (C.60);
        \draw[Arrow={cyan!40!blue}{1.2},->](CAR-3.120) |- ($(C)+(1,1)$) -| (C.30);
        %Drawing some repetitive things
        \foreach \txbehind/\Car [count=\j from 1]in {
            i+1/CAR-1,
            node\quad i/CAR-2,
            i-1/CAR-3,
            i-2/CAR-4,
            0/L%<-necessary
        }{
            \path($(CAR-1.-90)+(0,-0.2)$)coordinate (temp) -- (temp-|\Car.-90) node []{$\txbehind$};
            \ifnum\j<5
                \ifnum\j=2{}%modified
                \else%modified
                \draw($(\Car)+(0,4)$) node[draw, line width=2pt,anchor=180,font={\large},inner xsep=5pt,inner ysep=10pt]{$C_{\txbehind}$};%modified
                \fi%modified
                \draw[Arrow={cyan!40!blue}{1},->]($(\Car.90)+(0,2)$) -- ++(0,-2)node [pos=0.5, anchor=-180]{$U_{\txbehind}$};
            \fi
            \ifnum\j<4
                \draw[Arrow={red}{1},->](\Car.15) -- ++(0.75,0)node [midway, anchor=90]{$V_{\txbehind}$};
            \fi
        }
        
        \draw[Arrow2=-1,ArrowColor=black,Thickness=2mm,W=1.5cm,ArCorr=1.5] (CAR-2.140) -- (CAR-1.40);
        \draw(b)++(0,0.7em) node {$\tilde{U}_{i+1}$}; %notice that b node is defined in the marking style
        \draw[Arrow2=-1,ArrowColor=black,Thickness=2mm,W=1.5cm,ArCorr=1.5] (CAR-3.140) -- (CAR-2.40);
        \draw(b)++(0,0.7em) node {$\tilde{U}_i$}; %the b position is rewritten by the previous instruction
        \draw[Arrow2=-1,ArrowColor=black,Thickness=2mm,W=1.5cm,ArCorr=1.5] (CAR-4.140) -- (CAR-3.40);
        \draw(b)++(0,0.7em) node {$\tilde{U}_{i-1}$};%ditto
        \draw[dashed,green!50!black](CAR-2.south east)--++(0,-1) coordinate (temp1);
        \draw[dashed,green!50!black](CAR-3.south west)--++(0,-1) coordinate (temp2);%
        \draw[Arrow={green!50!black}{1},<->]($(temp1)+(0,1.5em)$)coordinate (temp) -- (temp -| temp2) node [midway, anchor=90]{$d_{i}$};
        
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}

Update
I used the tikz ducks library because, as you will see, it has a very picturesque variety of results and commands to obtain them randomly; If you see its documentation you will see all the effort of its authors in generating all that, maybe someone one day will do something similar with vehicles and other things and just for the love or whatever of TeX, but mainly to make an MWE, which means that You copy the code, paste it into your compiler and if you have all the packages, yes or yes, it will give you a result with perhaps some warnings.
Of course, as FZH suggests, the easy way is to include external files, just like the example he cited, but since everything to look good requires handling certain details, to begin with they will be in a node and therefore the anchor point is important, then that all the images are on the same scale, so that you can define them with a specific width, for this it is advisable to search for free vector files on the internet edit in inkscape, separe what you need, cut the canvas to the minimum vector size, export to pdf,png or jpg; pdf is better because it keeps the vectors.
In order to compile the following you must download the 4 PDFs from this link, CAR-1.pdf, CAR-2.pdf, .. etc there are more files but they are free to use, since they are copies of copies, there is also the original svg from where I got them... next save them in the same directory where you have your tex file. As you can see, you can replace them with whatever you want with the respective file name so that the compiler can find them.
RESULT:

CODE: (to compile it you need 4 external files in the same main.tex directory)
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,arrows.meta,backgrounds,decorations.markings}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[%Here you can define some tikz picture enviroment options
        font=\sf\scriptsize,%set al fonts of this environment \sf=serif family, and size of text
        Arrow/.style 2 args= {%Custom style arrow named Arrow, that has 2 arguments
            draw=#1,%Option draw=color, #1 is the first argument
            >={Triangle[angle=120:.5cm 0.3,scale length=0.5*#2,scale width=0.3*#2]},%It uses arrows meta arrow personalization, check visual tikz normal definition is ->
            line width=#2*1.2mm
            },
        ArrowColor/.store in=\ArrowColor,ArrowColor=black,%Some variable to use in other styles below
        ArCorr/.store in=\ArCorr,ArCorr=1.5, %Some variable to use in other styles below
        Thickness/.store in=\Thickness,Thickness=4pt,%Some variable to use in other styles below
        W/.store in=\W,W=5mm,%Some variable to use in other styles below
        Arrow2/.style={%custom style arrow using decoratins markings.
            draw=none,
            postaction={
                decorate,
                decoration={
                    markings,
                    mark= at position 0 %this draw will be the first mark at the start of the path
                    with {%Mark drawing definition
                        \begin{scope}[yscale=#1]%All is in scope to mirror it using the default argument #1, using as Arrow2=-1 or 1
                            \pgfmathparse{int(\pgfdecoratedpathlength/4)}%Obtain the leght of the path
                            \edef\H{\pgfmathresult/15}%Then adjuts to mach the size of coordinates to the lenght of the path.
                            \fill[fill=\ArrowColor]
                            (0,0)
                            to [out=90-15, in=180] (\H,\W/1.5) coordinate (b)
                            -- ++(\Thickness,0) -- ++(0,-1pt) 
                            to [out=180, in=90-15] (\Thickness,0)
                            -- (0,0);
                        \end{scope}
                    }
                }
            },
            postaction={
                decorate,
                decoration={
                    markings,
                    mark=at position 1 %this draw will be the last mark at the end of the path
                    with {
                        \begin{scope}[yscale=#1]%idem
                            \pgfmathparse{int(\pgfdecoratedpathlength/4)}%idem
                            \edef\H{\pgfmathresult/15}%idem
                            \fill[fill=\ArrowColor]
                            (b) %uses previos coodinate to draw in the marck
                            to [out=0, in=90+20] (\Thickness/2,\Thickness*\ArCorr/1.5)
                            -- (\Thickness*\ArCorr,\Thickness*\ArCorr/1.5)
                            -- (0,0)
                            -- (-\Thickness*\ArCorr,\Thickness*\ArCorr/1.5)
                            -- (-\Thickness/2,\Thickness*\ArCorr/1.5)
                            to [out=90+20, in=0] ($(b)+(0,-1pt)$)
                            -- (b);
                        \end{scope}
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        ]
        
        %Creating a weel for all cars
        \def\Weel#1{%\Weel{position}
            \draw[fill=white,shift={(#1)}](0,0)circle (0.3);
            \draw[fill=black!80, even odd rule,shift={(#1)}](0,0) circle (.3) circle (0.2);
            \draw[fill,shift={(#1)}](0,0) circle (0.08);
            \foreach \i in {1,...,12}{\draw[fill,shift={(#1)}](30*\i:0.1)--(30*\i:0.2)--+(90+30*\i:0.02);}        
        }
        
        % drawing the Cars from external archives, you may include vectors (svg for example) if you convert them to pdf format.
        \draw(0,0) node[anchor=-90](CAR-1){\includegraphics[width=3cm]{CAR-1.pdf}}; %\draw(position) node [node options](node_name){\includegraphics[graphic options]{imagefile}}
        \draw($(CAR-1.-90)+(4.5,0)$) node[anchor=-90](CAR-2){\includegraphics[width=3cm]{CAR-2.pdf}};
        \draw($(CAR-2.-90)+(4.5,0)$) node[anchor=-90](CAR-3){\includegraphics[width=3cm]{CAR-3.pdf}};
        \draw($(CAR-3.-90)+(4.5,0)$) node[anchor=-90](CAR-4){\includegraphics[width=3cm]{CAR-4.pdf}};
        \draw($(CAR-4.-90)+(3,0)$) node[scale=3]{$\dots$};
        \draw($(CAR-4.-90)+(6,1)$) node[scale=2.5, draw, thick](L){\scriptsize Leader};
        \Weel{$(L)+(-0.8,-0.7)$}
        \Weel{$(L)+(0.8,-0.7)$} 
        \draw($(CAR-2)+(0,4)$) node[scale=2.5, draw, thick](C){\scriptsize Controller l};
        
        %Drawing some Arrows
        \draw[Arrow={cyan!40!blue}{1.2},->](CAR-1.120) |- ($(C)+(-1,2)$) -| (C.150);% |:vertical -:horizontal
        \draw[Arrow={cyan!40!blue}{1.2},->](CAR-2.120) coordinate (temp) -- (C.-90-|temp);% node_coord intersectión perpendicular tipe (-| or |-)
        \draw[Arrow={cyan!40!blue}{1.2},->]($(L.90)+(0,0.5em)$) |- ($(C)+(1,2)$) -| (C.120);
        \draw[Arrow={cyan!40!blue}{1.2},->](CAR-4.120) |- ($(C)+(1,1.5)$) -| (C.60);
        \draw[Arrow={cyan!40!blue}{1.2},->](CAR-3.120) |- ($(C)+(1,1)$) -| (C.30);
        %Drawing some repetitive things
        \foreach \txbehind/\Car [count=\j from 1]in {
            i+1/CAR-1,
            node\quad i/CAR-2,
            i-1/CAR-3,
            i-2/CAR-4,
            0/L%<-necessary
        }{
            \path($(CAR-1.-90)+(0,-0.2)$)coordinate (temp) -- (temp-|\Car.-90) node []{$\txbehind$};
            \ifnum\j<5\draw[Arrow={cyan!40!blue}{1},->]($(\Car.90)+(0,1)$) -- ++(0,-1)node [pos=0.1, anchor=-180]{$U_{\txbehind}$};\fi
            \ifnum\j<4{}\draw[Arrow={red}{1},->](\Car.15) -- ++(0.75,0)node [midway, anchor=90]{$V_{\txbehind}$};\fi
        }
        
        \draw[Arrow2=-1,ArrowColor=black,Thickness=2mm,W=1.5cm,ArCorr=1.5] (CAR-2.140) -- (CAR-1.40);
        \draw(b)++(0,0.7em) node {$\tilde{U}_{i+1}$}; %notice that b node is defined in the marking style
        \draw[Arrow2=-1,ArrowColor=black,Thickness=2mm,W=1.5cm,ArCorr=1.5] (CAR-3.140) -- (CAR-2.40);
        \draw(b)++(0,0.7em) node {$\tilde{U}_i$}; %the b position is rewritten by the previous instruction
        \draw[Arrow2=-1,ArrowColor=black,Thickness=2mm,W=1.5cm,ArCorr=1.5] (CAR-4.140) -- (CAR-3.40);
        \draw(b)++(0,0.7em) node {$\tilde{U}_{i-1}$};%ditto
        \draw[dashed,green!50!black](CAR-2.south east)--++(0,-1) coordinate (temp1);
        \draw[dashed,green!50!black](CAR-3.south west)--++(0,-1) coordinate (temp2);%
        \draw[Arrow={green!50!black}{1},<->]($(temp1)+(0,1.5em)$)coordinate (temp) -- (temp -| temp2) node [midway, anchor=90]{$d_{i}$};
        
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}

Original
Well, sometimes it happens that socially you have to move people more effectively, so that they don't think that it is a typical "do it for me" case, that's why you should make the questions focused on particular cases and try to isolate them, of course. So even if you search you will find pieces of code that you can adapt, well not so easy if you still don't understand much, but well..., since I had the codes to do it, here I put a solution that at least completes the issue of arrows .
Blue Arrows from: How to draw a nice and complex flowchart (combining table and flowchart)
black curved arrows from: Add arrow to Helix code
RESULT:

MWE:
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,arrows.meta,ducks,decorations.markings}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
        >=Triangle,
        font=\sf\scriptsize,
        Arrow/.style 2 args= {draw=#1,-{Triangle[angle=120:.5cm 0.3,scale length=0.5*#2,scale width=0.3*#2]},line width=#2*1.2mm},
        CoilColor/.store in=\coilcolor,CoilColor=black,
        ArCorr/.store in=\ArCorr,ArCorr=1.5,
        Thickness/.store in=\Thickness,Thickness=4pt,
        W/.store in=\W,W=5mm,
        Arrow2/.style={
            draw=none,
            postaction={
                decorate,
                decoration={
                    markings,
                    mark= at position 0
                    with {
                        \begin{scope}[yscale=#1]
                            \pgfmathparse{int(\pgfdecoratedpathlength/4)}
                            \edef\H{\pgfmathresult/15}
                            \fill[fill=\coilcolor!50!black]
                            (0,0)
                            to [out=90-15, in=180] (\H,\W/1.5) coordinate (b)
                            -- ++(\Thickness,0) -- ++(0,-1pt) coordinate (c)
                            to [out=180, in=90-15] (\Thickness,0)
                            -- (0,0);
                        \end{scope}
                    }
                }
            },
            postaction={
                decorate,
                decoration={
                    markings,
                    mark=at position 1
                    with {
                        \begin{scope}[yscale=#1]
                            \pgfmathparse{int(\pgfdecoratedpathlength/4)}
                            \edef\H{\pgfmathresult/15}
                            \fill[fill=\coilcolor]
                            (b)
                            to [out=0, in=90+20] (\Thickness/2,\Thickness*\ArCorr/1.5)
                            -- (\Thickness*\ArCorr,\Thickness*\ArCorr/1.5)
                            -- (0,0)
                            -- (-\Thickness*\ArCorr,\Thickness*\ArCorr/1.5)
                            -- (-\Thickness/2,\Thickness*\ArCorr/1.5)
                            to [out=90+20, in=0] ($(b)+(0,-1pt)$)
                            -- (b);
                        \end{scope}
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        ]
        %Creating a weel for all cars
        \def\Weel#1{%\Weel{position}
            \draw[fill=white,shift={(#1)}](0,0)circle (0.3);
            \draw[fill=black!80, even odd rule,shift={(#1)}](0,0) circle (.3) circle (0.2);
            \draw[fill,shift={(#1)}](0,0) circle (0.08);
            \foreach \i in {1,...,12}{\draw[fill,shift={(#1)}](30*\i:0.1)--(30*\i:0.2)--+(90+30*\i:0.02);}        
        }
        
        \def\DuckCar#1#2#3#4[#5]{ %\OrigCAr{position}{orientation~restrcited~values~1~or~-1}{rotation}{color}[ID]
            \begin{scope}[shift={(#1)},xscale=#2,rotate=#3]
                \draw(0,0) coordinate (#5);
                \draw(0,2.2) node[minimum width=5em](#5-top){};%<--Added a point on top named nodename-top
                \shuffleducks\duck[\randomhead,scale=0.8,xshift=-3em,yshift=0.5em];
                \Weel{0.6,0.3}
                \Weel{-0.6,0.3}
                \ifnum#2=-1{\draw(0,0)++(0,2em)node[draw, rounded corners, rotate=-#3, font=\sf\tiny]{#5};}\fi
                \ifnum#2=1{\draw(0,0)++(0,2em)node[draw, rounded corners, rotate=#3, font=\sf\tiny]{#5};}\fi               
            \end{scope}
        }
        
        % drawing the Cars 
        \DuckCar{0,0}{-1}{0}{}[CAR-1]
        \DuckCar{$(CAR-1)+(4,0)$}{-1}{0}{}[CAR-2]
        \DuckCar{$(CAR-2)+(4,0)$}{-1}{0}{}[CAR-3]
        \DuckCar{$(CAR-3)+(4,0)$}{-1}{0}{}[CAR-4]
        \draw($(CAR-4)+(3,0)$) node[scale=3]{$\dots$};
        \draw($(CAR-4)+(6,1)$) node[scale=2.5, draw, thick](L){\scriptsize Leader};
        \Weel{$(L)+(-0.8,-0.7)$}
        \Weel{$(L)+(0.8,-0.7)$}
        
        \draw($(CAR-2)+(0,4)$) node[scale=2.5, draw, thick](C){\scriptsize Controller l};
        
        %Drawing some Arrows
        \draw[Arrow={cyan!40!blue}{1.2}](CAR-1-top.150) |- ($(C)+(-1,2)$) -| (C.150);
        \draw[Arrow={cyan!40!blue}{1.2}](CAR-2-top.150) coordinate (temp) -- (C.-90-|temp);
        \draw[Arrow={cyan!40!blue}{1.2}]($(L.90)+(0,0.5em)$) |- ($(C)+(1,2)$) -| (C.120);
        \draw[Arrow={cyan!40!blue}{1.2}](CAR-4-top.150) |- ($(C)+(1,1.5)$) -| (C.60);
        \draw[Arrow={cyan!40!blue}{1.2}](CAR-3-top.150) |- ($(C)+(1,1)$) -| (C.30);
        %Drawing some repetitive things
        \foreach \txbehind/\Car [count=\j from 1]in {
            i+1/CAR-1,
            node\quad i/CAR-2,
            i-1/CAR-3,
            i-2/CAR-4,
            0/L%
        }{
            \path($(CAR-1)+(0,-0.5)$)coordinate (temp) -- (temp-|\Car.-90) node []{$\txbehind$};
            \ifnum\j<5\draw[Arrow={cyan!40!blue}{1}]($(\Car-top.30)+(0,1)$) -- ++(0,-1)node [midway, anchor=-180]{$U_{\txbehind}$};\fi
            \ifnum\j<4{}\draw[Arrow={red}{1}]($(\Car)+(1.25,0.5)$) -- ++(0.75,0)node [midway, anchor=90]{$V_{\txbehind}$};\fi
        }
    
        \draw[Arrow2=-1,CoilColor=black,Thickness=2mm,W=1.5cm,ArCorr=1.5] ($(CAR-2)+(-0.4,1.5)$) -- ($(CAR-1)+(0.8,1.5)$);
        \draw(b)++(0,0.7em) node {$\tilde{U}_{i+1}$};
        \draw[Arrow2=-1,CoilColor=black,Thickness=2mm,W=1.5cm,ArCorr=1.5] ($(CAR-3)+(-0.4,1.5)$) -- ($(CAR-2)+(0.8,1.5)$);
        \draw(b)++(0,0.7em) node {$\tilde{U}_i$};
        \draw[Arrow2=-1,CoilColor=black,Thickness=2mm,W=1.5cm,ArCorr=1.5] ($(CAR-4)+(-0.4,1.5)$) -- ($(CAR-3)+(0.8,1.5)$);
        \draw(b)++(0,0.7em) node {$\tilde{U}_{i-1}$};
                
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}


@J Leon V. Thank you so much, You helped me a lot. I just have one more question, how can I replace the duck car with cars like the original figure

@mzn, the easiest way is to substitute the definition of a duckcar for an image of your own. This answer might help with the insertion of external figures.

@mzn,, I updated the code so that you can place whatever it is in that context and you do not get errors due to the customization of that code, otherwise please consult this manual that has all the basics, if you consult the basics here you may get some bad reactions or I don't know Otherwise, when consulting, please cut the images.

@ J Leon V. I really thank you very much ,Do you mean I shouldn't post image here?

@ J Leon V. How can I change the size and font type of the word "controller" in the block?

@mzn , This is the most basic, before the word you can specify the size you want with certain latex nmonics, in this case it is in \scriptsize, you can change it to all available types, such as \normalfont, \small, etc. Do you know that you can ask GPT chat all this? and explains it to you by generating codes.

@mzn , Well, although it is not very accurate, it is better to consult Google what you want and then enter tex stack exchange, generally it will send you to the best answer,the search engine built into the site is not so good, check the following links: Tikz: Style which only scale the text inside a node , Adjusting font size with TikZ picture.

@J Leon V. Thank you.
I also used the same commands that you said, but because I did not get the result I wanted, I asked you

@mzn Will there be a link where I can see the final result of what you require? I don't know if it is something that can be solved with the basics or if it requires something new.

@J Leon V.
\draw($(CAR-2)+(0,4)$) nodescale=2.5, draw, thick{\tiny Controller i}; In this part of the code, I want to make my font size smaller and change my font type.

@mzn in the tikz picture options: \begin{tikzpicture}[         >=Triangle,         font=\sf\scriptsize, %\sf mean to use serif family, change here with you want for te font in the environment.

@J Leon V. I want to add three more boxes smaller than box 2(controller i)  above each car, what should I do?

@J Leon V. I use this code ,\draw($(CAR-3)+(2,4)$) nodescale=2.5, draw, thick{\tiny Controller };but I want to change the size of my block. How can I make the block size smaller?

@mzn, To control all the sizes of the node, first you have to change the scale, in this case it is with 2.5, play with other values ​​like 1 or 0.75 and see what happens; then you can change the font size using font=\tiny, or others, it is useful if you have multi-line text, maybe if you put only \tiny the font change will be ineffective so you should put font=\tiny\sf

@J Leon V. Thank you, What I mean is that I want to have control over the size of the blocks, for example, one is 3 in 1 and the other is 6 in 1.

@mzn you have the node modifiers node[minimum height=value,minimum width=value], in this post there is a style P that can help you.

@J Leon V. Thank you, I want to put a block above the first car and then draw an arrow from that block to the first car, but I don't know how to increase the size of this arrow (height of the arrow)in my code. Is it possible to guide me in which part of the code should I change?

@mzn add the next lines: \draw($(CAR-1)+(-3,2)$) node[scale=2.5, draw, thick](NT){\scriptsize New Text};   \draw[Arrow={cyan!40!blue}{2},<-](CAR-1.180) -| (NT.-90); where CAR-1 is the nmonic of the position of the car 1, then +(3,-2) is the shift x and y values where draw the new node called NT with the text content "New Text", then the next line draws the arrow  from CAR-1 poit oriented at 180 degrees to NT poir oriented at -90 degrees; the arrow has cyan!40!blue color and width value is 2.

@J Leon V. I updated my desired figure again. I want to draw an arrow from each block  c  one to the cars. Is it possible to guide me in which part of the code should I change?

@mzn I added things I hope it helps, but try playing with the values ​​and see what happens

@J Leon V. Thank you very much for your guidance. Your answer is very useful for me.
